# Prevent Click Event from document Level to child elements

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I am create a hybrid app using [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) frame work where I have a setting screen, when setting screen is visible in the screen I want to prevent all the touch event from the user to other components except specific views. I saw some of the post saying that event the stopProgation() and preventDefault() will the event further But i am not clear about It.

I tried to add click event to document to release my setting list from the view when user tap on the screen but if the user tap on other component in that screen it will trigger that button action also, how to prevent this.

Also I don't want to prevent the action of touch when user click on setting list or some specific component in my view.

**Note:** I not able to use `jquery` in this project because using `jquery` side by with `Sencha` may cause performance issue.

**Code:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ControlPanel.ControlPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: "widget.controlpanel",
    requires: [
                   'Ext.SegmentedButton'
    ],
    config: {
        layout: {
            pack:'stretch'
        },
        docked:'bottom'
    },
    documentClickHandler:function(event){
        console.log('Document Clicked');

        document.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);

        var settingListContainer = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#setting-list-container")[0];
        if (settingListContainer) {
            var controlpanel = settingListContainer.up('controlpanel');
            if (controlpanel) {
                controlpanel.remove(settingListContainer, true);
                var segmentButton = controlpanel.down("#control-segment-button");
                if (segmentButton) {
                    segmentButton.setPressedButtons();
                }
            }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;;
    },

    onSegmentToggled: function (container, button, pressed)
    {       
            console.log("Toggle Event");
            var index = container.getItems().indexOf(button);
            if (index == 0) {
                if (pressed) {
                    container.setPressedButtons();
                    var settingListContainer = this.down("#setting-list-container");
                    if (settingListContainer) {
                        this.remove(settingListContainer, true);
                        // close nav by touching the partial off-screen content

                    }
                }
            }a
            else {
                var settingListContainer = this.down("#setting-list-container");
                if (!pressed&&settingListContainer) {
                    this.remove(settingListContainer, true);
                }
                else if (pressed) {
                    var existingList = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('settingList')[0];
                    if (existingList) {
                        this.add(existingList);
                        document.addEventListener('click', this.documentClickHandler, false);
                    }
                    else {
                        this.add({ xtype: "settingList", height: '349px', sortHandler: this.config.sortHandler, segmentControl: container });
                        document.addEventListener('click',this.documentClickHandler, false);
                    }
                }
            }

    },
    listeners: [
        {
            delegate: "#control-segment-button",
            event: 'toggle',
            fn: 'onSegmentToggled'
        }
            ],
    initialize: function () {
        //Ext.require("");
        var segmentedButton = Ext.create('Ext.SegmentedButton', {
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'center',
                align: 'stretchmax'
            },
            docked: 'bottom',
            id:'control-segment-button',
            allowMultiple: false,
            allowDepress: true,
            config: { flex: 1 },
            items: [
                {
                    iconCls: 'time',
                    width: '50%',
                    cls:'palin-segment',
                    style:"border-radius:0px"
                },
                {
                    iconCls: 'settings',
                    width: '50%',
                    cls: 'palin-segment',
                    style: "border-radius:0px"
                }
            ]
        });
        this.add(segmentedButton);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault(); is what keeps the framework or the document from also handling this event.